# I want to call javascript function in url.action as parameter in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameters

```
Url.Action("actionName","ControllerName",new { extraData = getdata()});
```

getdata() is a javascript funcion and I want to use it like

```
public ActionResult actionName(string extraData)
{
*/ bla /*
}
```

Has anyone any Idea?

Comment: What do you exactly want? Like this the javascript function `getdata` will be executed and its result will be passed via the variable `extraData` to your controller...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is client side and C# is server side so that is not going to work. It looks like you're using MVC, so why not create a route for this situation? Then the url can be manipulated with javascript on the client, and your server code remains the same.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "newRoute", // Route name
    "NewRoute/{extraData}", // URL with parameters
    new
        {
            controller = "ControllerName",
            action = "ActionName",
            extraData = string.Empty
        }
    );
```

Then on the client you may have a link as below:

```
<a id="myLink" href="about:blank">My Link</a>
```

And you can use your javascript to manipulate this link as required:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").href = "/NewRoute/" + getData();
```

I've had to make many assumptions here, so if this doesn't answer your question then you might need to add a little more detail about what you're trying to do.